# Reading from a CSV file using CPP, compiling the code with a CMake file

Tags: c++, csv, cmake

I am writing a piece of code in c++. The program should read data from a CSV file and then do some processing, before writing it to another CSV output file. My program read in the file correctly when I compile it with:

```
make version1.cc
```

However, when I try to compile it with my CMakeLists.txt, it doesn't even go looking for the file. I tried this thusfar, with no success:

```
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT Output.csv
   COMMAND version1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Input.csv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Output.csv
   DEPENDS version1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Input.csv
   )

add_executable(version1 version1.cc Output.csv)
```

I have also tried the following, still with no luck:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
SET(MY_CSV_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/House1-July-Complete.csv")
CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version1.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version1.cc @ONLY)
```

Comment: What I see from your CMakeLists.txt: you target 'version1' depends on 'Output.csv', which is itself depends on 'version1'. Sounds like cyclic dependency to me. Perhaps you should use add_custom_command(TARGET t target POST_BUILD...) see http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html

Comment: Just a thought- in general, programs like this may be more useful if you set the path at runtime (via command line args, etc), than at compile time with cmake. What if you want to move the file someday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

```
add_executable(version1 version1.cc)

set(input_csv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Input.csv)
set(output_csv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Output.csv)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT  ${output_csv}
    COMMAND version1 ${input_csv} ${output_csv}
    DEPENDS version1 ${input_csv}
)

add_custom_target(process_csv
    ALL   # means that this custom target is also included in the ALL target
    DEPENDS ${output_csv}
)
```

Calling `make`, `make all`, or `make process_csv` should then work.

Comment: This one worked for me. I also had to add inputFile.open as it got lost along my many ways of trying this problem out :)